# Formatted drive with Wubi installation, Windows boot manager menu still shows option

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I had Ubuntu 12.04 installed with Wubi on a partition of my main HDD and decided I would do a proper installation of it. In the process of prepping the drive, I foolishly formatted the partition before uninstalling Ubuntu and because of that, the entry on the Windows boot manager menu was never removed either.

How might I go about fixing this problem? I'm hoping to be able to remove that entry and disable the menu.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you're going with an Ubuntu-only computer, ie ridding yourself of that virus called Windows, ;) then I would boot from a LiveCD/USB and then reformat the HDD and then install Ubuntu.

If you're going to dual boot with Windows, then you should still do similar to above, but instead only reformat the ext4 partition, as Ubuntu uses ext4 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste a screenshot. When you install Ubuntu-Wubi, there is no Grub menu, the Ubuntu Wubi makes a listing along with Windows OS in Windows Boot Manager.

But when you make a clean install i.e. ext4 partition, Grub loader gets installed. So whatever the previous windows based options including Ubuntu-Wubi were, they would go in the fourth line of Grub as Windows Based OS/ Other Operating Systems.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I managed it fixed. And yes I actually meant the Windows Boot Manager. Sorry for the confusion. I found a command in the prompt that let me remove the entry from the boot manager (BCDEdit) and it went smooth. Thanks for all the help!

Also, happily running Ubuntu 13.04 here and loving it!